# Is it possible to decrypt HTTPS website user activity?

Tags: decryption, isp

Can Governments order an ISP to decrypt data about any user's personal information. If there is some information, for example, that some terror suspect has been active on an HTTPS website on the internet, is it technically possible to decrypt his activity on the website?

HTTPS is secure because of encryption. Can the government ask the ISP to decrypt it? Or is it not technically possible?

Comment: "decrypt his activity on the website" -- that's not how HTTPS works. HTTPS encrypts the ***traffic***. The website keeps logs of user activity that are not, and do not need to be, encrypted.

Comment: And frankly, this question is already answered in your other question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/240416/can-my-isp-know-these-things  "the vast majority of traffic are protected by HTTPS, so the ISP have no much knowledge on anything you do"

Comment: @schroeder hmm..how long do ISPs *in general* store encrypted data for? I mean, is there really a range like 5-6 years? Or do they store indefinitely?

Comment: @JayShah: ISP in general don't store the traffic at all. This would be way too much data and way too costly. But government agencies often have interfaces to the ISP or to internet exchanges which allows them to copy __selected__ traffic to their own systems.

Comment: @JayShah Imagine the amount of data needed to do that. I have a 200 Mb/s downstream, meaning I could download ~788 TB per year. My local ISP has 135.000 customers, so if all use that plan and download non-stop, that would lead to 100 Exabytes in data. By comparison, Google is estimated to store between 10 and 15 Exabytes of data.

Comment: @JayShah: As I said: ISP do not store the data but will probably provide interfaces so that government itself can copy selected data. Also, please don't just reference comments you've asked somewhere else - ask here again what you want to know.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich So what is all the conversation about data storage [on the internet?](https://www.google.com/search?q=data+storage+ISP&oq=data+storage+ISP&aqs=chrome..69i57.3311j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Okay I will type them here. Many Islamic countries have restrictions regarding homosexuality, anti-Islamic views on websites etc..I am essentially asking about the feasibility about Govt officials tracking each and every person saying anti-Islamic things on popular websites. I have some concerned Muslim friends who are so worried on this fearing one day some Government official would come to their residence with evidence of their activity obtained from ISP (by the research paper method) to arrest them.

Comment: So is there any chance ISPs eventually dispose off encrypted data? Like after 6 months or 1 year? Why would they really store encrypted data? If they do not keep encrypted data for much time, it would be a big sigh of relief for my Muslim friends.

Comment: @JayShah: Again and again, the ISP does not have the capacity to store all traffic and would not be able to decrypt it anyway. It might still be that some information can be gained from stored meta data, like information about DNS lookups. And it can of course be that the endpoints of the communication could be compromised already, like having a backdoor or similar installed on the end user device. Don't focus too much on the ISP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Online traffic monitoring by ISP for safety purposes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/197628/online-traffic-monitoring-by-isp-for-safety-purposes)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich *"...government agencies often have interfaces to the ISP or to internet exchanges which allows them to copy **selected** traffic to their own systems."* --- Any example of what this **selected** traffic could be? Homosexual material?

Comment: @JayShah: Nah, they cannot select by content since the content is encrypted. They might for example select traffic by target IP, target geographic are or by the or where the traffic comes from (i.e. target a specific user). But also government is really limited regarding encrypted traffic. The best option is usually to compromise the endpoints of the connection to get access to the traffic before encryption or after decryption.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich But they could select by unencrypted domain like www.homosexualbeings.com?

Comment: @JayShah: Might be, but then they still cannot decrypt any captured HTTPS traffic on this domain. But if temporarily plain access was done  (not uncommon, because browsers default to HTTP and web sites then redirect to HTTPS) they might for example redirect the user to a similar looking site controlled by the government and capture everything there or try to infect the user. See [this report from EFF](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2018/03/we-still-need-more-https-government-middleboxes-caught-injecting-spyware-ads-and) for more.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for the information. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

#### TLS 1.3: Not unless the Government knows something we don't.

TLS is built upon different cipher suites. A cipher suite is a set of algorithms used for key exchange, encryption and authenticity. TLS 1.3, for example, supports the following cipher suits:

- `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`
- `TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256`
- `TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`
- `TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256`
- `TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256`

As you can see, most of it depends on AES in GCM- and CCM-Mode and SHA-256, as well as ChaCha20-Poly1305. These algorithms are currently considered secure, but it's possible that a government has found a way to crack them within a reasonable amount of time. Is that likely? No, I'd say it's very unlikely, but it is within the realm of possibility.

#### TLS 1.2 and below: Depends on the configuration.

TLS 1.2 and below used a radically different design philosophy. Instead of offering only a handful of cipher suites that are expected to all offer high standards of security, TLS 1.2 was built around the idea that there should be as many different cipher suites, so that every possible need would be covered.

As you can imagine, when you throw every possible algorithm at the wall, you'll get quite some ciphers that are not considered secure anymore, such as:

- `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5`
- `TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA`
- `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_RC4_128_SHA`

Of course, this is not an extensive list, but it should give you an idea of what one could be dealing with. There are attacks against these algorithms, which allow an attacker to compromise the confidentiality and integrity of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

> Can Governments order an ISP to decrypt data about any user's personal information

What kind of personal information? If its PII like identity/social security number, government already have it.

> Can the government ask the ISP to decrypt it? Or is it not technically possible?

HTTPS is using SSL/TLS standard. Meaning to be able to decrypt the message, you need to have the private key for that encrypted message, which only stored in the web server.

Comment: You don't necessarily need the private key - the session key is actually what you need.

Comment: By personal information, I mean the user's activity. See the example in the question about the terror suspect.

Comment: @JayShah I guess there is something like Legal/Lawful Interception which the website owner has to comply. But it is a contrary against GDPR.

Comment: @JayShah also try to check out NSA's global surveillance leaked by Snowden :)